# Phonegap Barcodescanner won't start after function fired

Tags: javascript, cordova, plugins

I've tried to create a simple app with the barcodescanner plugin but it seems like it won't fire properly after i try to make it call.

Phonegap build recognises the plugin and the app starts without problems, but the button won't fire a scanning event. Maybe the barcodescanner might not even start. I aint quite certain but at that point I should have gotten an error before starting the app.

I've tried to test the app on both Android and Windows with no result.
I've also tried to use an older build of phonegap to no result. I am using 3.7 at the moment.

I've also tried alternative approaches as to try and create a /phonegap create projectname with adding plugins platform etc. Still same result.

**My HTML and JS**

```js
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
   function scan() {
  cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(
      function (result) {
          alert("We got a barcode\n" +
                "Result: " + result.text + "\n" +
                "Format: " + result.format + "\n" +
                "Cancelled: " + result.cancelled);
      }, 
      function (error) {
          alert("Scanning failed: " + error);
      }
   );
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
 <title>Roargame</title>
</head>
<body>

 <button data-icon="search" onclick="scan()">Scan ME NOW!!!!</button>
 


 <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="barcodescanner.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

My XML Config

```html
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.testdomain.barcode" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0">
    <name>Roargame</name>
    <description>
        Test barcodescanner
    </description>
    <author email="nota@mail.com" href="https://testdomain.com">
        Some Random Name
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner" version="2.2.0" />
    <icon src="icon.png" />
</widget>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your javascript console for errors.

Comment: I did. No errors i'm afraid.
Tried some unit testing as well. All positive.